# Specify an output message for successful test case

Tags: nunit

Each `Assert` allow to define `error message` which will be printed out in case of assert failure but can I somehow provide a message which will be outputed in case of successful test run?

Comment: I dont know how to achieve that but ,why would you need that?
There is a point in showing an error-stack trace; which helps programmer to
correct it.But i do not see a point in showing a customized success message.

Comment: For some test cases I want to track this information whilst running tests using continuous integration system which persists logs for each build. Also when I want to see some test run info I can just run tests and see this info in console rather than handling at breakpoint or using some output like logging or System.Diagnostics.Debug

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`Assert.Pass`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5.1) utility method.

Comment: But this results in a SuccessException being thrown, resulting in a failed test. Surely this defeats the purpose?

Comment: @Carl - which NUnit version are you using? And which test runner?

Comment: @Peter - NUnit 2.5.5 and TD.NET 3.0.2749

Comment: @Carl : From NUnit docs: The Assert.Pass method allows you to immediately end the test, recording it as successful. I'm using NUNit. I'm using 2.5.10.11092 and all working fine, may be this is TD.NET specific behaviour?

Comment: @Peter: Possibly, I'll give it a go in the Gui runner when I get a chance and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see any message in NUnit's SharpDevelop output with this solution.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - what versions of NUnit is the SharpDevelop runner built for? Might be that support for the 'Pass' method is not implemented...

Comment: @PeterLillevold: The first output in the console says *NUnit-Console version 2.6.2.0*. The assembly version of `NUnit.Framework.dll` linked to test projects seems to be 2.6.2.12296.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - ah so it actually uses the NUnit console to drive the tests. Well, trying out the default behavior here, nunit-console does not display the Passed message in the console. However, the TestResults.xml structure will contain the passed test including the message. Not sure which product to blaim here, SharpDevelop for not using the xml output, or NUnit for not printing Passed messages to the console output :)

Answer (score 38):

I just use   `Console.WriteLine( "Your message here" );`    which will be directed to the NUnit output so you can see Test passed messages

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the NUnit version integrated into SharpDevelop.

Comment: Just for updating the last info... now #develop does show console output. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've said that you want this information for use by your continuous integration environment. Presumably your CI environment is using the [NUnit-console Runner](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.5.1)?

If so then I recommend making use of the XML output generated from each test run, and example of which can be found [here](http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.5.1/files/TestResult.xml).

The XML output contains results for each and every test. You haven't said which CI server you're using, but it should be straightforward to build a step into your build process to import this XML and mine it for the stats you need.

Comment: This is what I exactly do, using XML output. But additionally I want to have some messages along with test

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me an example of the sort of message that would be useful? If the tests are passing, the message would presumably always be the same...?

Comment: Following your example It would be great to have smth like - <failure><message>...</message> but for successfull tests too

Comment: When there's a failure, there's specific data you need to debug the test, so a message makes sense. But for success, what would a useful message be, above and beyond "Passed, again, as expected."

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `NUnit.Framework.SuccessException` and print the message:

```cs
try
{
    // assert
    Assert.Pass(sOutput);
}
catch (SuccessException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return;
}
```

As a result you should get the output message under clicking Output:

[image: Test Output]

Comment: The `try/catch` is needed because [Assert.Pass](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Pass) throws an exception. It seems like [Smectymnuus'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12239668/2615878) answer effectively does the same thing as this answer but with just one line of code. (I'm using V.S. 2015 and NUnit 3.11.)